# Android > 4.4.2 - Setting Default SMS App

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I've been walking through the steps required to allow Android to recognize an app as a potential default Messaging (SMS/MMS) app detailed [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) and I've followed through on several posts on SO that have up-voted answers that fallback to the instructions outlined on the blog posting.

However, even after following these instructions, which I believe I have done so correctly, I'm still not able to get my app to appear in the system dialog which will allow me to choose which app I want as the default Messaging client. I can't help but feel like I'm still missing something in the manifest but I'm not too sure. If anyone has any advice on this, I'd really appreciate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.gregfmartin.smsdemo">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:name=".ApplicationCore"
                 android:theme="@style/SmsDemo">
        <!-- Listens for incoming SMS Messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".components.receivers.SmsReceiver"
                  android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Listens for incoming MMS Messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".components.receivers.MmsReceiver"
                  android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity -->
        <activity android:name=".Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".components.activities.ConversationThreadViewer">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="sms"/>
                <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
                <data android:scheme="mms"/>
                <data android:scheme="mmsto"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Headless SMS Handler -->
        <service android:name=".components.services.HeadlessSmsSenderService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPONSE_VIA_MESSAGE"
                 android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="sms"/>
                <data android:scheme="smsto"/>
                <data android:scheme="mms"/>
                <data android:scheme="mmsto"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I'd poke around and try to find another third-party SMS client that *does* show up for you. Then, use [App Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.japanesecrackers.appbrowser) to peek at its manifest and note any differences. You could also check the manifest of the pre-installed SMS client through the same tool. Your manifest seems to match [the official blog post on the matter](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html), so it's not obvious to me what might be missing.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I took your advice and found an app called hellotext that, after installed, appeared in the system dialog. When I was using AppBrowser (excellent app which I'd never heard of before - thanks for that!) to inspect the manifest, the only real difference I'd noticed was the inclusion of android.intent.action.VIEW in the Activity responsible for sending messages which mine didn't have.

I tried doing a bit of a Draconian approach and adding all permissions that their app had which didn't work. I tried using a signed APK instead of a debug which didn't work either. I'm lost :/

Comment: Did adding that action string to your `<intent-filter>` solve the problem?

Comment: Nope. It still won't show up. I'm starting to wonder if this is one of these strange issues with 4.4.4. Maybe a bit paranoid but I've been having all sorts of really strange issues with this version of Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on. I know I kicked myself after I figured it out and facepalmed for about ten minutes.

The Service, HeadlessSmsSenderService, the permission is supposed to be android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE not android.permission.SEND_RESPONSE_VIA_MESSAGE.

Respond/Response

Seriously? Send Respond?

What caught it was I copied and pasted the manifest from the Google Blog Post and just made a new app really quick that used it and low and behold, it showed up in the system dialog. So then I ran a diff against it and my manifest and everything matched up save for that misspelling (and the organizational changes that I had).

The nasty part about this is that there are some permissions and Intent Actions that IntelliJ won't automatically catch while you're typing them. I'm also not sure if Lint will catch these types of semantic errors or not. For all intents and purposes, the app will compile and run cleanly. No output was found on logcat so really this was a near totally silent issue.

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the category

```
android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING
```

Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either. I added this category to the main Activity and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Additionally, after digging around in apps that do actually work on this device, like hellotext, this category isn't included anywhere in the manifest yet it still is recognized by the system as a potential default messaging app.

Comment: No. My fix below was what the problem was. Thank you though.

Comment: Ok.. Ohh I missed that part.